# creating My first Django App

Tags: python, django

here's my code :

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode

class SignUp(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)


   def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.email)
```

here's what i get . please help thank u.

```
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

                                                                ^
```

IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Hi. python is the language which has very strong identation policy. just read this http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a tab character before `timestamp`. You should either use spaces or tabs to indent Python, never both. Your editor may show the indentation looking correct but it may not match how Python understands a tab.

[PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) says use only spaces.

Comment: i might just copied it wrong, its written well in editor i just don't know why it doesnt work

Comment: I am telling you for a fact that there is a tab character there. What editor are you using? Please delete all the spaces before `timestamp` and put them back using only the space bar.